# Kik bot made using Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, chat, flask

I created a Kik messenger bot using Flask microframework and python that accepts POST requests on the provided webhook and then responds appropriately. I have excluded custom module imports because they are not relevant in my problem.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from flask import Flask, request, Response, url_for
from kik import KikApi, Configuration
from kik.messages import LinkMessage, PictureMessage, VideoMessage
from kik.messages import StartChattingMessage, ScanDataMessage, StickerMessage
from kik.messages import SuggestedResponseKeyboard, TextResponse
from kik.messages import messages_from_json 


app = Flask(__name__)
BOT_USERNAME = os.environ['BOT_USERNAME']
BOT_API_KEY = os.environ['BOT_API_KEY']
WEBHOOK = os.environ['WEBHOOK']

features = {'manuallySendReadReceipts': False,
            'receiveReadReceipts': True,
            'receiveDeliveryReceipts': False,
            'receiveIsTyping': False}

static_keyboard = SuggestedResponseKeyboard(
    responses=[TextResponse('PLACEHOLDER1'),
               TextResponse('PLACEHOLDER2')
               ])

kik = KikApi(BOT_USERNAME, BOT_API_KEY)
kik.set_configuration(Configuration(
    webhook=WEBHOOK, static_keyboard=static_keyboard, features=features))


@app.route('/incoming', methods=['POST'])
def incoming():
    if not kik.verify_signature(request.headers.get('X-Kik-Signature'),
                                request.get_data()):
        return Response(status=403)

    messages = messages_from_json(request.json['messages'])

    for message in messages:
        user = message.from_user
        chat_id = message.chat_id

        if isinstance(message, LinkMessage):
            # do something

        elif isinstance(message, PictureMessage):
            # do something

        elif isinstance(message, VideoMessage):
            # do something

        elif isinstance(message, StartChattingMessage):
            # do something

        elif isinstance(message, ScanDataMessage):
            # do something

        elif isinstance(message, StickerMessage):
            # do something

        elif isinstance(message, TextMessage):
            query = message.body
            query_words = query.split()
            chat_type = message.chat_type
            participants = message.participants

            if query.lower() in ['placeholder1', 'placeholder2']:
                # do something

            elif query_words[0] in ['placeholder3', 'placeholder4']:
                # do something

            elif query_words[0] in ['placeholder5'] and user in ['mamun']:
                # do something

            # a large number of more elif statements present in actual app
            else:
                # do something

    return Response(status=200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

What I have done so far is create separate modules for custom functionality that I created, but in the end they are consumed by the large number of elif statements which I don't like. Is there any way I can avoid the elif statement hell?

My actual bot is 100% complete, production ready and approved by kik, but the way I had to program it still bothers me when I look at it.

Comment: You can simplify the `elif`s by using just one `if`. I would write an answer, but I am confused by the removed sections of code. Do you want the `pass`es?

Comment: I use functions imported from my own modules in place of pass es. I removed them to make it more clear as to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could just build a dictionary mapping classes to functions to call:

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

def func_a(x, y):
    return x + y

def func_b(x, y):
    return x - y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = {LinkMessage: link_message,
         PictureMessage: picture_message,
         VideoMessage: video_message,
         StartChattingMessage: chatting_message,
         ScanDataMessage: data_message,
         StickerMessage: sticker_message}
    message = PictureMessage()
    funcs[message.__class__]()
```

Alternatively, if these classes are controlled by you, you could give them all a method called the same name which will be called, maybe `handle_message`:

```
class LinkMessage:
    ...
    def handle_message(self, *args):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    message = LinkMessage()
    message.handle_message(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are importing from the packages multiple times. Combine them into a single set:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, Response, url_for

from kik import KikApi, Configuration
from kik.messages import (LinkMessage, PictureMessage, VideoMessage,
    StartChattingMessage, ScanDataMessage, StickerMessage,
    SuggestedResponseKeyboard, TextResponse,
    messages_from_json)
```

---

Instead of referencing environment variables directly as key of dict, use the `.get` call or better yet, [`os.getenv`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/library/os#os.getenv) method. This will not raise an error if the variable is not set.

---

When searching for substrings inside lists, better to search them inside a set (or tuple). The lookups are [quicker in a set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2831242/1190388) than list.

```
if query.lower() in ('placeholder1', 'placeholder2'):
# or
if query.lower() in {'placeholder1', 'placeholder2'}:
```

Additionally, if these values are not dynamically retrieved, you should store them as variables outside of the function body. This will also reduce the creation penalty you might face.

---

You could reduce the `if-else` nesting by following the advice [@Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/176505/12240) has in the other answer. For a more verbose cleanup, you might have to provide snippets belonging to those if-else blocks.

Comment: `('placeholder1', 'placeholder2')` is not actually a set, as you say in your comment. It should be `{'placeholder1', 'placeholder2'}`. However, for such small things the construction time of a `set` over a simple `tuple` might not be worth it.

Comment: @Graipher Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed and added another point for the construction penalty.